# SQL query with having count with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to retreive records based on a joined table's number of associations with a condition. In plain English the query would be:

*Get all properties where the number of associated `logs` having `action` one of ('foo', 'bar', 'moo') is less than 5 (can also be NULL). So to be more exact, it can have 10 logs, but if 4 or more of them have action one of ('foo', `'bar', 'moo') then it should not be included.*

Without the count condition is working, even though I am not sure it includes the ones with no logs:

```
SELECT p.id
     , count(l.object_id) 
  FROM properties p
  LEFT 
  JOIN logs l
    ON l.object_id = p.id
   AND l.object_type = 'Property'
 GROUP 
    BY p.id 
 HAVING (count(l.object_id) < 5);
```

The problem is if I want the condition specified above, it does not work (syntax is obviously wrong).

```sql
SELECT properties.id, FROM `properties` LEFT OUTER JOIN `logs` ON
    -> `logs`.`object_id` = `properties`.`id` AND `logs`.`object_type` = 'Property'
    -> GROUP BY properties.id HAVING (count(logs.object_id where logs.action in
    -> ('foo', 'bar', 'moo')) < 5);
```

**NOTE:** The logs table has over 10 milion records... I have tried with a nested `select where`, but it is not an option as the query times out.

Comment: Something like `HAVING count(case when logs.action in ('foo', 'bar', 'moo') then 1 end) < 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql the condition can be written as:

```
HAVING SUM(logs.action in ('foo', 'bar', 'moo')) < 5
```

In case there are no matches from the the table `logs` the above sum will return `null`, do if you want these rows returned use `COALESCE()`:

```
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(logs.action in ('foo', 'bar', 'moo')), 0) < 5
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, however I think it is not including the properties where there are no logs, any idea how to include them as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly. They should be returned

Comment: My bad I did not see it 